# How to save only single request and response in saz file?

Tags: fiddler

I need to save a session in HAR or SAZ formats. If I use fiddler to do it now I have all the requests and responses. Id like to limit things to request and response to html document only or to json response or any resource I need. Is there a way to do this in fiddler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To save a single Request/Response pair in a SAZ file, select it and choose File > Save > Selected Sessions > In ArchiveZip.

To save a single Request/Response pair in a HAR file, select it and choose File > Export Sessions > Selected Sessions.

To do this from script or an extension, simply call the `WriteSessionArchive` method, passing an array containing just 1 Session object.

Answer (score 2):

I do this:

1. Press F12 to stop capture
2. Delete any of the traffic you don't want.
3. File - Save All Sessions.

This enables me to save a .saz file with only 1 request/response inside.  I hope they fix this so you can choose to do this under save selected sessions.